# Emailed RDP file will open in Microsoft "RD Client" App but won't add on iOS?

Tags: ios, remote-desktop

Given that I can open the file; how do I import it and add it to the "RD Client" list of machines so it can be opened without finding the file and without retyping every thing again?

I'd like to import the file.